# concatenate char * to string

Tags: c++

I have a function which is expecting a string, I was wanting to concatenate const char * to a string to be returned.

Here is example code to help illustrate this scenario:

```
void TMain::SomeMethod(std::vector<std::string>* p)
{
  p->push_back(TAnotherClass::Cchar1 + "/" + TAnotherClass::Cchar2);
}
```

and here is the other class these are from:

```
class TAnotherClass
{
 public:
   static const char * Cchar1;
   static const char * Cchar2;
};

const char * TAnotherClass::Cchar1 = "Home";
const char * TAnotherClass::Cchar2 = "user";
```

im getting the following error:
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char*' to binary operator +

Why is this not valid? please help

Comment: And in addition to what’s been said, don’t pass a pointer into the method, use a reference instead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char const*` cannot be used with `+` operator, as the error says.

What you need to do is this:

```
p->push_back(std::string(TAnotherClass::Cchar1) + "/" + TAnotherClass::Cchar2);
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^ notice this
```

It creates a temporary object of type `std::string`, then you can use `+` with it. It concatenates the strings, creating temporaries all the way, and finally passes the final string to `push_back`.

Apart from that, as @Konrad noted in the comment, *don’t pass a pointer into the method, use a reference instead*, as:

```
void TMain::SomeMethod(std::vector<std::string> & p) //<-- note & 
{
  p.push_back(std::string(TAnotherClass::Cchar1)+"/"+TAnotherClass::Cchar2);
}
```

Comment: More specifically, there is no overload taking two `const char *`s.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid the std:: conversionas mush as possible but if thats the only way then :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to add two pointers.  The + operator can't be overridden for char*.

You can do this:

```
p->push_back(std::string(TAnotherClass::Cchar1) + "/" + TAnotherClass::Cchar2);
```

Keep in mind the fact that `std::string(...)` as used above is a C-style cast using functional notation.  It's equivalent, in this case, to `static_cast<std::string>(...)`.

Whether you allow function style casts in your code is up to you.  Some policies are against ALL C-style casts.  In my previous workplace this particular use of them was allowed, but no other.