# convert char to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to reduce a string by giving it to a function. For example, if i have `"abrakadabra"`, the function shall return a string of `"abrkd"`. Which means that all characters should exist only once in the return value.

I have the following function:

```
string textletters(string text) {
    string ret = "";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ret += str;
        } else {
            bool exist = false;
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (text.at(i) == text.at(j) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exist) {
                ret += str;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I know that `text.at(i)` gives a `char` back. But I want to convert this `char` to a `string` so I can concatenate it.

Comment: You don't have to. `std::string`'s operator `+=` can append a `char` just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [concatenate char \* to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553892/concatenate-char-to-string)

Comment: @Boumbles Not really a dupe of that question, but probably still a dupe.

Comment: The code that accesses the content of `text` is in a loop, running through the valid indices into `text`. There is no need to check validity with `text.at(i)` inside that loop. Just use `text[i]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `push_back` method to append single char to a `std::string`. You can also use `operator +=` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I propose yet another approach:

C++ comes with a lot of container logic.

You can convert your string to a `set`, which allows only one element of each value:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

std::string input("akrakadabra");
std::set<char> only_once(input.begin(), input.end());
```

Downside of this is that the letters are sorted afterwards, and not in the order of first appearance in the string, but you didn't specify whether you needed a specific order.

You can convert the `set` back to a `string` using the range constructor, too:

```
std::string result(only_once.begin(), only_once.end());
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

That is typically done with a `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::stringstr ss;
...
ss << text.at(i);
...
std::string result = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the titular question, while as others have noted, is not actually useful for this problem:

There's a `std::string` constructor which takes a character and a repeat count.  So to create a string consisting of a single character, you can use a repeat count of 1:

```
string(1, ch)
```

But this is quite wasteful, even on implementations with a small-string optimization.  So simply append your character directly to your existing string as Andrew suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I need to review my C++ courses but, for the moment, I just could help you with an example with VisualBasic code, may it could bring you a newer idea to reach it, check what I did:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function DeleteRepeated(Text As String) As String
Dim length, i As Integer
length = Len(Text)
Dim NewText, Char As String
NewText = ""
For i = 1 To length
Char = Mid(Text, i, 1)
If InStr(1, NewText, Char, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
NewText = NewText & Char
End If
Next i
DeleteRepeated = NewText
End Function
```

Here is what you are looking for, Now on C++ as you requested, if you have any question just tell me, hope it helps:

```
// Delete Repeated Char in String
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string UniqueInString (string MyString)
{
  string chr,NewText;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<MyString.length(); ++i)
    {
    chr = MyString.at(i);
    if (NewText.find(chr) == string::npos)
    {
    NewText = NewText + chr;
    }
    }
  return NewText;
}

int main ()
{
  string z = "abrakadabra";
  cout<< UniqueInString(z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an implication that the returned character sequence should have the characters in the original order, but if that's not an actual requirement, then the solution is easy:

```
std::string res = text;
std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
auto last = std::unique(res.begin(), res.end());
res.erase(last, res.end());
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the lambda solution:

```
  string res = "abrakadabra";

  res.erase(remove_if(res.begin(), res.end(), [&res](const char& c)
  { return find(res.c_str(), &c, c) != &c; }), res.end());

  cout << res << "\n";
```

output: `abrkd`